# finding values of different decimal places with Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

I am working on json web data of a table in order to make it look exactly like the original version's representation.
 It has some id values to each rows, so I am trying to use this ids as "keys" to recover the original order of rows in a table.

But interestingly it has different decimal places on the same numbers like 45.097 as opposed to 450.97.

What is the most efficient way to match those same numbers with different decimal places? Will it be better if I convert it(now it's in pandas dataframe type) into Numpy array?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a short example?  See the page about writing a [MCVE].

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ASGM; for example, 1097648982760 is represented as 1097648.98, so I am thinking of just extracting the first 4~5 digits of numbers but there are numbers like 0.15, making things complicated.

Comment: Exactly - those complications are going to determine what makes an answer good or not.  We can't really help unless you decide how you want the code to deal with different examples (like 0.15).

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has `float64` dtype.

If you are not sure what you have or your numerics are saved as strings, you can always "float64" your column.

```
df['column']=df['column'].astype('float64')
```

To check what you have just type: `df.info()`

If it doesn't work of your have problems converting the numbers try this:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce')
```

This will ignore the conversion errors.

> Will it be better if I convert it(now it's in pandas dataframe type) into Numpy array? Thank you in advance.

Although Pandas is built to work on Numpy, you don't need to grab Numpy arrays and convert them, instead use pandas [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) conversion.